# How to reference foreign keys in OGC API Features (pygeoapi)?

Tags: ogc-api

I'm using a modified version of the PostgreSQL provider in pygeoapi, and I want to keep the relations between tables in my OGC API Features. Does the standard have a solution for this? I thought the solution was to add the reference table to the links, but I don't see a "relation name" in the [list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) for this case.